# How to execute program which have created Qt on windows?

Tags: qt

Basically, Qt provide the cross-plateform.

I have made a application which is used Qt creator on Linux.

But, I can't be running that on Windows because it can't find .dll files such as mingw10.dll and qtcore4.dll, etc.

So, I have copied the .dll files which can be found in qt/bin directory.

And, I create a directory in order to save that like /lib becuase of distribution of application.

But, I can't set up path in .pro file.

How to set up the path for .dll?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify a bit: I understand you managed to compile the application under Windows and have just problems running it. Did you use QtCreator on Windows, too? Can you run it from the IDE directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can too [compile QT statically](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/deployment-windows.html#building-qt-statically) in order to not have to link dlls to your exe.

Answer (score 1):

You say you've successfully compiled the app, so the only problem is that it can't find the DLLs.

There are a few solutions, and they have nothing to do with the .pro file.  Your two best bets are:

- Make sure the DLLs are in the same directory as the .exe file
- Make sure the DLLs are in a directory contained in the `PATH` environment variable